# iPhone Phonegap Assign Phonenumber crashes

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to assign a string to a new contact phone number.

```
              alert(email +"" + brokerNombre+ "" + phoneNumber);
            var myContact = navigator.contacts.create();
            myContact.displayName = "Hi";
            myContact.phoneNumbers = [phoneNumber];
```

Setting .phoneNumbers results in :

2013-03-04 08:58:35.294 Concierge[6489:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xa24af10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key value.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14f012 0x26bae7e 0x1d7fb1 0x12a9d1d 0x121600b 0x1215fbd 0x2c5b7 0x2c8bb 0x2cb0c 0x2b12a 0xe7a6 0xfb6c 0x2b65731 0x2b74014 0x2b647d5 0xf5af5 0xf4f44 0xf4e1b 0x34eb7e3 0x34eb668 0x38affc 0x2bfc 0x2b55)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: wt is [phoneNumber] ??

Answer (score 0):

Try myContact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumber; by removing the square brackets.